# C# Convert a Dictionary<int, byte[]> to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, byte

I am having an API call which returns a `Dictionary<int, byte[]>`

```
var receiptData 
= await GetAsync($"Services/GenerateReceiptForPrint?
transactionId={transactionId}");
```

`receiptData` is of type  `Dictionary<int, byte[]>`
and I want to get the `byte[]` of it.

Comment: Please consider reading our [ask] topics before asking a question. Have you tried anything?

Comment: as you don't say how you want to conver `Dictionary<int, byte[]>` to `byte[]` I assume you want a binary object serialization: `using (var formatter = new BinaryFormatter()) { using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) { formatter.Serialize(stream, receiptData); var receiptDataArray = stream.ToArray(); } }`

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` is a collection of `Keys` and `Values`. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

In your case, the keys are `int`s, and the values are byte arrays.

To get the first value out of a dictionary that must only have one entry, you would reference the entry by its key; something like:

```
if(receiptData.Count() != 1)
    throw new Exception($"receiptData Dictionary should have exactly 1 entry, but has {receiptData.Count()}");
var myByteArray = receiptData[0] // gets the value of the first entry in the dictionary
```

But what if there is more than one entry in the dictionary?

You should read carefully through the Microsoft reference document.

Comment: there is only one entry in the dictionary

Comment: @beans, _"there is only one entry in the dictionary"_ - this absolutely must be mentioned in your question :D

Comment: Even though your response should only have one entry, that is not a restriction that exists in the `Dictionary` class. So you should additionally inspect the returned dictionary, ensure that it contains one and only one entry, and throw an error if it doesn't.

Comment: I updated response per comment re: only one entry in dictionary